# Pygame : change screen color on key press

Tags: python, colors, pygame

I'm new to pygame and I'm trying to get a key-press to change the `screen.fill` color. I'm going to include the code below any help/tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
white = (255,255,255)

background_color = (0,0,0,)
(width, height) = (800, 600)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Color Test')
screen.fill(background_color)

pygame.display.flip()

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            background_color = white
            print('left pressed')
            pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fill the screen after you are change the value of `background_color`.

```
...
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        background_color = white
        print('left pressed')
        screen.fill(background_color) #<--- Here
        pygame.display.update
    ...
```